# jquery map() function returns undefined

Tags: jquery, dictionary

i got a problem with the map function, maybe i got it wrong.
i have a menu that consists of div layers (here is one item)

```
<div class='menu_item inner_node' hash='4' depth='0'>Portfolio</div>
```

if some one click it the css class selected is added to that item.
now i want to get all selected menu items with map() like this:

```
$("div.selected").map(function()
{
    return $(this).attr("hash");
}
).get().join(", ");
```

i just need the "hash" attribute from it.
i made an example here: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gruhH/)
the output is undefined everytime...
what is wrong with the script?

regards,
peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `return` in function `get_hash()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/gruhH/1/

Comment: use `toggleClass` instead of `if else`